# How to search a key value in mongodb based on tag name in a deeply nested document?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo-3.x

```
 db.props.aggregate([{"$match":{release:"1"}},{"$project":{'_id':0, 'SHK.0':{"$filter":{"input":'$SHK.0.host',"as":'fil', "cond":{$in:['$$fil.Tags',"cd"]}}}}}])
```

I used the above to query my dataset listed below ::

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a0eafdf481fc70d171521b1"), 
    "release" : "1", 
    "product" : "1", 
    "project" : "1", 
    "patchset" : "1", 
    "common" : { 
        "active" : "YES", 
        "javahome" : "path" }, 
    "SHK" : [ 
        { 
        "host" : { 
            "value" : "demo", 
            "Tags" : [ "ci", "cd" ] }, 
        "appserver" : { 
                "value" : "demo", 
                "Tags" : [ "ci" ] }, 
        "appname" : { 
            "value" : "demo", 
            "Tags" : [ "cd" ] } } ] }
```

But the above does not seem to work I am getting a blank index ... I am trying to get here specific key value pair according to the tag name present suppose in the above query as i have mentioned cd i should get value for only host and appname and appserver should not be listed in the end result as it does not contain the tagname cd. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like that:

```
db.props.aggregate([{
        "$match": {
            release: "1"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$SHK'
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            '_id': 0,
            'tag': {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": '$SHK.host.Tags',
                    "as": 'fil',
                    "cond": {
                        $in: ['$$fil', ["cd"]]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

You need to `$unwind` the first array, in this case "SHK". After unwinding (flattening) "SHK", the only array is the "Tags" field. So then you can apply the `$filter` operator. Also you were missing the `[]` in your `$in` condition. You wrote:

```
{$in:['$$fil.Tags',"cd"]}
```

but $in operator is build like that:

```
{ $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }
```

so in this case:

```
$in: ['$$fil', ["cd"]]
```

Comment: This works well  not exactly the output i wanted but gave me if a particular key contains that tag or not which I then compared programmatically and deleted the keys where these tags were not present. Thanks